# Why I am getting NullPointerException in my ternary operator?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ternary-operator

My ternary operator is throwing a `NullPointerException` even though I explicitly check if the value of my list is `null`. However, if I add parenthesis around the ternary operator, my code works.

Code without parenthesis (throwing the exception):

```
final List<String> listData = null;
System.out.println("Insert new data (Created Monitorings) : " + 
        listData != null ? listData.size() : 0);
```

Code with parenthesis (working fine):

```
final List<String> listData = null;
System.out.println("Insert new data (Created Monitorings) : " + 
        (listData != null ? listData.size() : 0));
```

Can somebody explain it how exactly it is working.

Comment: NullPointerException is not compilation error

Comment: @GhostCat Yes!!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is about [precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) of operators: the String`+` has a much higher precedence than following ternary operator.

Therefore your first snippet actually does this:

```
( "Insert new data (Created Monitorings) : " + listData ) != null 
  ? listData.size() : 0
```

Meaning: you concat a string (with a null `listData`), and compare that against null. Obviously that concat'ed string isn't null. Thus you do call `listData.size()`. And that resembles to `null.size()` which leads to your NullPointerException.

You are comparing the **wrong** thing against null! In the second snippet the ( parenthesises ) ensure that the result of ternary operation gets added to your string.

Answer (score 1):

in snippet one the value that is compared to null is `"Insert new data (Created Monitorings) : " + listData`

Answer (score 0):

'+' has more precedence than '!='

Hence Snippet 1 translates to:

(**("Insert new data (Created Monitorings) : " + listData)** != null ? listData.size() : 0;

The expression is not null so it proceeds to listData.size(). But as it is null, it throws the exception.